# Get installated path for an app in valve's steam on windows using java?

Tags: java, path, registry, steam

I am writing a small tool using Java that needs to find location of an application installed on the disk by steam.

Is it feasible to get installation path of an application installed by valve's steam distribution platform on a windows system if its appid is known?

I've tried searching registry but no dice, apparently valve stores list of installed apps and their location somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Visit here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Steam/comments/4e58ue/dev_project_preview_notes_about_steam_settings_in/), I'm working on the same thing in Delphi lol.

Comment: Too late I did the exact same thing to get it working but anyways your answer is correct